# X2Go Client could not start X11 server. (macOS Catalina)

Tags: macos, unix, macports, xquartz

I'm trying to connect to the server which already set up via X2Go Client. After enter the password, this prompt shows up:

---

**X2Go Client could not start X11 server.**

X2Go Client requires XQuartz to be installed.

If XQuartz is already installed on your system,
please select the correct path in the now upcoming dialog.
Refer to the end of this message for path examples,
in case you do not know the exact location yourself.

Should you have not installed XQuartz yet, please
follow the outlined steps:

MacPorts users, please install either the port xorg-server
or the port xorg-server-devel.
Upon successful installation, please follow the instructions printed
by the port utility to autostart/load the server.

All other users, please obtain and install XQuartz from:

https://www.xquartz.org/

Afterwards, restart X2Go Client and select the correct path
to the X11 application in the general X2Go Client settings.
This will most likely be

/Applications/MacPorts/X11.app

or

/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app

---

So I follow the instruction by installing:

1. the port xorg-server and make sure that it's installed. I can use port command like `$sudo port -v selfupdate` and also `$man port` to see information
2. XQuartz at /Applications/Utilities/

nothing seems to happen. The same prompt shown up again. When I click "ok", there is a window details about X2Go Client settings. I set it accordingly to the recommendation above "/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app". It still didn't work.

I also try (suggested by: https://www.owsiak.org/x2go-issue-on-macos-catalina/)

```
$sudo rm -rf /tmp/.X11-unix
```

It didn't work as well. Some one please help.

Answer (score 1):

This error is addressed in this [issue](https://github.com/snowdream/dockerfiles/issues/6)

It seems we have to switch to an earlier version of X server (`XQuartz-2.7.7`), see  as per the link, to the bottom

Comment: I could not get XQuartz-2.8.2 working with X2go on Ventura 13.1 (M1), no matter what the source or what I tried. Downgrading to 2.7.2 worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Big Sur version 11.6.8 (chip: Apple M1), you can install XQuartz using brew:

```
brew install --cask xquartz
```

Note: Restart your Mac after installation.

For me XQuartz-2.8.2 was installed and the X2Go Client works correctly.